# How do you get the final date choice from a date type input element?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, dom-events

When you create a input element with the type date, modern browsers present a date picker. I've noticed that Firefox, and also other browsers fire a "change" event on every change of the date, so when you are flipping through months or years, a "change" event is fired, even if you are not done selecting the date you want. Is there a way to tell when the menu is closed and the choice is "final"? There only appears to be "input" and "change" as event types. I was hoping there would be a "closed" event or something similar.

I tried to workaround this by listening to blur events on the element but it doesn't blur unless you click away, so when you click on your final date choice and it disappears by itself, it hasn't blurred. I expected this but I had to try.

So, is there any way to tell when it has closed and the user has made their "final" choice and they aren't just flipping through the calendar?

Comment: Maybe you can listen to the `change` event and store the value somewhere; what is saved is a 'last choice' if not overriden by another explicit 'submit'…

Comment: What other browsers? This doesn't happen in Chrome or Edge from my tests. The behavior in Firefox is because when you navigate the month/year selectors it actually changes the value of the input box. In Chrome it doesn't change the input value until you actually click on a date(day), and in Edge it similarly doesn't change the input value until you click the "accept" button.

Comment: In any case, I don't think there is a way to check if the calendar has closed. It probably would be better to provide some other way for the user to indicate that their date selection is "final" instead of trying to take action immediately upon them selecting a date.

Comment: @Herohtar Thank you for your input. Please add an answer that it is not possible and if nobody else can prove you otherwise then I will accept your answer. I am currently using a button to confirm that they are done, but I was hoping I could avoid it, and also avoid importing a custom date-picker library just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is currently no way to tell if the calendar is open or closed, nor is there any event that fires upon it closing.**

The `change` and `input` events both seem to be triggered under the same circumstances -- specifically, when the text in the input box is modified. This happens when the user selects a date from the calendar, but also when they type directly into the box.

If you want a consistent user experience, the best option would be to use a custom date picker, as the appearance and behavior of the calendar differs across browsers.